# How to clearly display inline editable attributes?

Tags: inline-edit

What is the best way to display inline editable attributes among non-editable ones.

E.g. (image attached) Name and Notes can be edited, while Source and Order no. not.[image]

Comment: I'm not quite sure I know what you mean. Do you have an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Attached image to be more precise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invite users to inline edit not only on hover?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61797/invite-users-to-inline-edit-not-only-on-hover) and [Prompt user to edit an inline-edit field](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28494/prompt-user-to-edit-an-inline-edit-field)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would look for if I wanted to see if something was editable, in this scenario, would be a small pencil/pen icon. A simple underline might also indicate I could click there and edit the content.